# Apollo with service worker in a Next.js project

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have a NextJS prototype live at https://www.schandillia.com/blog. The data displayed is being pulled off a Strapi installation at https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql. I also have the entire codebase up on Github at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/web (the frontend).

I'm using an Apollo client to interface with the graphql source. And also a service worker set up to enable PWA.

Everything's working fine except I'm unable to cache the query results at the browser. The service worker is able to cache everything else but the results of Apollo queries. Is there any way this could be enabled? The objective is:

1. To be able to use some kind of prefetching of query results at the server.
2. To be able to have the results cached at the browser via service worker.

The three files relevant to this issues are as follows:

**Apollo Setup**

---

```
// web/apollo/index.js

import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { withData } from 'next-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

// Set up cache.
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

// Configure Apollo.
const config = {
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql', // Server URL (must be absolute)
  }),
  cache,
};
export default withData(config);
```

**Query Component**

---

```
// web/pages/PostsList.jsx

import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const renderers = {
  paragraph: props => <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom {...props} />
};

const PostsList = ({ data: { error, posts } }) => {
  let res = '';
  if (error) res = (
    <Typography variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom>
      Error retrieving posts!
    </Typography>
  );
  if (posts && posts.length) {
    if (posts.length !== 0) {
      // Payload returned
      res = (
        <Fragment>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <div>
              <Typography variant="display1" gutterBottom>{post.title}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>{post.secondaryTitle}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom>Post #{post._id}</Typography>
              <ReactMarkdown source={post.body} renderers={renderers} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      res = (
      // No payload returned
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom>
          No posts Found
        </Typography>
      );
    }
  } else {
    res = (
    // Retrieving payload
      <CircularProgress />
    );
  }
  return res;
};

const query = gql`
  {
    posts {
      _id
      title
      secondaryTitle
      body
    }
  }
`;
// The 'graphql' wrapper executes a GraphQL query and makes the results
// available on the 'data' prop of the wrapped component (PostsList)
export default graphql(query, {
  props: ({ data }) => ({
    data,
  }),
})(PostsList);
```

**Blog Page**

---

```
// web/pages/blog.jsx

import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import withRoot from '../lib/withRoot';
import PostsList from '../components/PostsList';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 20,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  },
});

class Blog extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js'); }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const title = 'Blog | Project Proost';
    const description = 'This is the blog page';
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>{ title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} key="description" />
        </Head>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Typography variant="display1" gutterBottom>
            Material-UI
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            <Link href="/about">
              <a>Go to the about page</a>
            </Link>
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            <Link href="/blog">
              <a>View posts</a>
            </Link>
          </Typography>
          <Button variant="raised" color="primary">
            Super Secret Password
          </Button>
          <Button variant="raised" color="secondary">
            Super Secret Password
          </Button>
        </div>
        <PostsList />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Blog.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    root: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

// Posts.propTypes = {
//   classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
// };

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(Blog));
```

The service worker in question is as follows (redacted for brevity):

```
// web/offline/serviceWorker.js

const CACHE_NAME = '1b23369032b1541e45cb8e3d94206923';
const URLS_TO_CACHE = [
  '/',
  '/about',
  '/blog',
  '/index',
  'apple-touch-icon.png',
  'browserconfig.xml',
  'favicon-16x16.png',
  'favicon-194x194.png',
  'favicon-32x32.png',
  'favicon.ico',
  'manifest.json',
];

// Call install event
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(cache => cache.addAll(URLS_TO_CACHE))
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// Call activate event
self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
  // remove unwanted caches
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cache) => {
          if (cache !== CACHE_NAME) {
            return caches.delete(cache);
}
        })
      );
})
  );
});

// Call fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
  );
});
```

Please advise!

Comment: "results cached at the browser via service worker." Why do you want to do that via service worker ? There is library for apollo [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist). Should be enough to store data on client side and receive it when user offline

Comment: I did consider apollo-cache-persist, but am somehow unable to make it to work (getting "window not defined" error) with NextJS. Would you be able to advice what tweaks I need to make in my apollo/index.js file to successfully incorporate this module? Here's what I tried:

```
if (process.browser) {
  persistCache({
    cache,
    storage: window.localStorage,
  });
}
```

Comment: "window not defined" is because you run your code on server side (your are using next.js to precompile pages). You should enable apollo-cache-persist on client side only. Though it will be tricky I guess. But you want a lot of features and that is expected :)

Comment: @TheLearner have you been able to accomplish what you asked here? If so, can you please share it?